# Rails bundler gem update error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm updating a DreamHost shared server environment thusly:

"which ruby" => /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

"gem query rails" => rails (4.0.3)

Created a barebones app and got the following Rack error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": In Gemfile: rails (= 4.0.3) depends on bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0) Current Bundler version: bundler (1.0.7) Your version of Bundler is older than the one requested by the Gemfile. Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`. (Bundler::VersionConflict)

So I did the update: "gem install bundler":

"gem list bundler" => bundler (1.5.3)

Rails is not picking up the new gem. (Identical error message.) I know this is a noob question - what am I missing?

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails s` ?

Comment: Thanks @sidney - this uncovers a related issue.

>gem install activesupport -v '4.0.3' ==> OK

>bundle install ==> complete!

>bundle check ==> all dependencies OK

>bundle show activesupport ==> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.3

Rack says it can't find activesupport-4.0.3. Head scratcher.

Comment: Sorry I don't know where can it comes from :s Good luck !